# Eclipse giving incorrect answer to equation

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm pretty new to working with Eclipse but my uni classes demand I use it and it doesn't seem to follow BODMAS for some reason.

```
    
    public static double readabilityIndex(int words, int sentences, int characters) {
        double index;
        index = 471*(characters/words) + 0.5 * (words/sentences) - 21.43;
        return index;
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner text_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the text you'd like analysed: ");
        
        String text = text_input.nextLine();
        text_input.close();
        List<Character> characters = convertsStringtoCharList(text);
        //System.out.println(characters);
        int number_of_words = countWords(text);
        System.out.println(number_of_words);
        int number_of_sentences = countSentences(text);
        System.out.println(number_of_sentences);
        int number_of_characters = countCharacters(characters);
        System.out.println(number_of_characters);
        double readabilityScore = readabilityIndex(number_of_words, number_of_sentences, number_of_characters);
        System.out.println("The readability score of the text submitted is: " + readabilityScore);
    }

}
```

`

The values being passed in are integers but that doesn't seem to be causing the problem, characters = 38; words = 10; sentences = 1.
By my working I should be getting 1773.37 but eclipse keeps returning 1396.57 and I can't pinpoint why.

I've tried hardcoding values in and keep getting the same issue, I've also tried adding more brackets to the equation to make it more set in stone how it should be done but neither have worked.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Eclipse. Eclipse is just an IDE. This is about Java - and your incorrect expectation about how integer division works. When `characters` has a value of 38, and `words` has a value of 10, then the value of `characters / words` is 3, not 3.8.

Comment: If you want `characters / words` (and indeed `words / sentences`) to be performed in floating point arithmetic, you should cast one of the operands to `double`.

Comment: Also, for equal precedence operators, the operations and casting go left to right.  So `38/10/(double)2` will produce 1.5, not 1.9 since the 38/10 is first computed as an `int`  and only then division by a double yields 1.5.

Comment: Cast everything to double type: `index = (471d * (double)characters/(double)words) + (0.5d * ((double)words/(double)sentences)) - 21.43d;`. Doing this, `index` will hold `1773.37`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd-退した  It may be a safe way of doing it but It is not necessary to cast everything to a double.

Comment: I realize that. It's just a crazy little personal rule I have for doing calculations involving doubles and resulting in double.